# Appearance defined by PDFAppearance class dont apply to Signature Field

Tags: itext, itextpdf

i am working through the Paper: Digital Signatures for PDF documents.
I am working with the .Net Dlls of ITEXT and i wrote this Code similar to example 2.6 of that paper:

```
Private Sub Method()
    'step   1:  Create a Document
    Dim document = New Document()

    'step   2:  Create a PdfWriter
    Dim file = "C:\Export\ITEXT.PDF"
    Dim FileOutputStream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    Dim writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, FileOutputStream)

    'step   3: Open the Document
    document.Open()

    'step   4: Add content
    document.Add(New Paragraph("leeres Signaturfeld"))

    Dim signatureFormField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer)

    signatureFormField.FieldName = "FieldName"
    signatureFormField.SetPage()
    signatureFormField.SetWidget(New Rectangle(150, 750, 250, 800), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE)
    signatureFormField.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT)

    writer.AddAnnotation(signatureFormField)

    Dim tp = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(writer, 72, 48)
    tp.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.GRAY)
    tp.SetColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY)
    tp.Rectangle(0.5F, 0.5F, 71.5F, 20.5F)
    tp.FillStroke()
    tp.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE)
    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(tp, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, New Phrase("SIGN HERE"), 36, 24, 25)
    signatureFormField.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp)

    'step   5: Close the Document
    document.Close()
End Sub
```

But the Appearance defined by the PDFAppearance class dont apply to my empty Signature field, i just get a empty field without text.
What did i wrong?

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue; as I feel more at home with C# than VB, I translated it line-by-line, so there should not be any difference in behavior.

So I was quite surprised when after opening your file in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, I could clearly see the appearance:

[image: ITEXT.PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC]

So I opened it in my ancient Adobe Acrobat 9.5 to inspect the file, but what did I see:

[image: ITEXT.PDF in Adobe Acrobat 9.5]

Oops...

But probably it has to do with the ribbon above. And indeed, after releasing the mark-fields button I got:

[image: ITEXT.PDF in Adobe Acrobat 9.5, mark-fields button released]

So I assume your issue may depend on the PDF viewer you use and the state it is in. This actually corresponds to the specification which states that *individual annotation handlers may ignore this entry and provide their own appearances.*

---

One remark, though: I would propose you do

```
writer.AddAnnotation(signatureFormField)
```

after

```
signatureFormField.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp)
```

i.e. add the annotation only when it is completely finished.

Otherwise the signature field may already have been written to file before you finished creating the appearance

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Your answer cleared my Problem.